# Why stop my data transmission when i change the size of my application at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

Hi first of all info´s about the project: I develop an application to receive serial data over a COM port. For that i use Visual Studio 2015 with C# and winforms.

That is the way how i receive the Data at the winform application.

```
...
//create a Stream for the Port
SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
//read the incoming data
string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
if (sendDataFlag == 1)//sendDataFlag is used for a "StopShowData" Button
{
 //show the data in the RichTextBox
 //with the StreamManage i sort the incoming data
 this.Invoke((Func<string, bool>)StreamManage, indata);
}
```

The way to repeat the error: When i start my application i must click on Start-Button to display data in a RTB. When i now change size of my application direct after the start i didn't longer receive data over the Port. I didn't receive an Error so i didn't know what i have to do.

I hope someone can say me what i have to do or what can i change to prevent the bug.

With friendly wishes Sniffi

Comment: What do you mean with "change size of my application" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "change size of my application"? You will have to add some more code, `StreamManage` for instance, to give us an idea what is failing. What have you already tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: @ x... I mean what i write, click with the mouse on a corner and pull the window bigger or smaller.  @Bastian Thiede the StreamManage is only for  evaluate the data but when i change the size i didn´t receive data so that this method has nothing to do with the bug. It´s a problem with receiving the data from the Port, that´s the reason why i didn´t post this method (it´s really big^^)

Comment: I have read at msdn that the ReceiveDataHandler has a problem with change the size but there is nothing how i can fix it. My Problem is that the most user start the application and than they change the size to their favourite. I hope someone know what i can do, i want that the user can change the size.

Comment: when you make a derank for the Question pls write as comment why so i can fix it.

Comment: Does your code working on a UI thread (i.e. on the event handler of the button click event) or are you running this code on a separate worker thread?

Comment: All run in the same thread. I haven´t a click event i only set a flag when the user click on the start-button and with this flag i start the monitoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the code that reads from serial port on a separate worker thread. It looks like the UI messages processed by the UI thread may prevent your serial port reading code.